# Acrobat SDK get document path from CAcroPDDoc class object

Tags: c#, acrobat-sdk

Using,

```
CAcroPDDoc PdDocObj = AvDocObj.GetPDDoc() as CAcroPDDoc;
```

I am able to retrieve PdDocObj, but unable to find any property/method that provides me pdf file-location.

Answer (score 0):

From PDDoc you can init the JSObject (set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject) and then use something like jso.path, which will give you the device-indepentend path of the document.

OK. Following a complete working VBS example. Good Luck, Reinhard

```
Info = "View the path of the active doc" &vbCR &"Acrobat must be opened with an active document"
OK = MsgBox(Info, vbQuestion+vbYesNo)
if OK = vbNo then WScript.quit

Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AVDoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc
set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject
ffn = jso.path
msgbox(ffn)
```

Comment: I tried this, var jsObject = PDDocObj.GetJSObject(); But getting nothing in jsObject, Data field of that object has enum which is empty and niether there is class JSObject in c#, Any Clue?

Comment: I don't know C# and how to work with that with ActiveX elements. However I put an complete working VBS example in my answer, so you can test that